# Was there a separate 순우리말 for 200?

Tags: history-of-korean, numbers

We have 순우리말 for single-digit numbers: 하나, 둘, 셋, 넷, 다섯, 여섯, 일곱, 여덟, 아홉.

We have also 순우리말 for multiples of 10: 열, 스물, 서른, 마흔, 쉰, 예순, 일흔, 여든, 아흔.

But what about multiples of 100? The (now-obsolete) 순우리말 for 100 is 온, but were there separate 순우리말 for multiples of 100 from 200 to 900? And what about 1000(즈믄)? In general, how were big numbers spelt in 순우리말?

Answer (score -2):

There is no such pure Korean word for 200, 300, 2000, 3000, etc.

Please see the answer of the National Institute of Korean Language. (국립국어원)
https://korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=221690

Another article found at the forum of the Korean Language Society (한글학회) website.
https://hangeul.or.kr/%EC%98%A4%EC%88%9C%EB%8F%84%EC%88%9C%ED%95%9C%EB%A7%88%EB%8B%B9/3234280

Comment: @jick I understand your concern. I think it was not very clear, so I accepted the suggested edit for my response so it is now clear that it is not the official opinion of the Korean Language Society, but just a user's opinion on the forum.

Comment: @user13229973 You are right. I flagged this person's comment.